# jquerymobile: target page not refreshing when called by mobile.changepage useing reloadpage:true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to load a page via an ajax call using `mobile.changepage` shown below:

```
mobile.changePage( "index.html", {transition: "slide", reloadPage: true, data: id})
```

I've tried to use on the `index.html` all the functions such as:

```
$( '#mainMenu' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){var movie_id = location.search;});
```

The page gets loaded but I can not get the value of "id" on the `index.html` page, just if I hard refresh it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Rodrigo

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or live code ?

Comment: You will need to post relevant HTML. It sounds like you're expecting code in the `<head>` of a document to be included during AJAX navigation, which isn't the case, but that's just a guess on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you will pass a single parameter to `page2`, you could use `location.search` in `page2` to get the movie variable, but I found that it doesn't work well for regular browsers. So, in the result page, you need to parse `$(this).data('url')`.

Also, the script code in `page2` must be inside the `DIV#page2` block, because what is in your header HTML WON'T be changed when next page is changed (as another member noticed).

The script blocks:

**page1**

```
<script language="javascript">

    $( '#mainMenu' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
        $('.btnTxtSearch').bind('click',function () {
            var movieName = $('#txtMovieTitle').val();
            if (!movieName || movieName.length == 0 || movieName == null) {
                alert('Please insert a title before clicking the button');
                return false;
            } //end of if

            $.mobile.changePage( "page2.html", {transition: "slide", reloadPage: true, data: movieName}); 

        });
    });

</script>
```

**page2**

```
<script language="javascript">
//Without this pageinit may be called multiple times in back and forth use case.   
$('#page2').die( 'pageinit');

$('#page2').live( 'pageinit',function(){
    var movieName = $(this).data('url').split('?')[1];
    //Debug:
    alert(movieName);
});     


</script>
```

Comment: I added 2 simple pages to show the issues I am having, page1.html is a simple page that after clicking the button it does a $.mobile.changePage and calls the page2.html, but there is no way I can initiate the page2.html from the $.mobile.changePage   http://www.goemobile.com/mobile/page1.html

Comment: I just put the changes in place and still not working. for some reason the page $('#page2').live( 'pageinit',function(){ never gets called from the $.mobile.changePage ... it just works if I refresh the page from the browser button.. Any ideas page I am using http://www.goemobile.com/mobile/page1.html

Comment: Yeah, if you call the second page via URL (e.g. http://www.goemobile.com/mobile/page2.html?id=123) you can see the changes were good. Now to finish it.

Comment: The `SCRIPT` block (containing your custom code) is inside the `HEAD` tag. You gotta take the whole thing, `<SCRIPT language="javascript"> ... </SCRIPT>`, CUT and paste between the tags `<div data-role="page"> ... </DIV>` in each page.